# Mac OS 10.9 fatal error: 'tr1/unordered_map' file not found

Tags: macos, command-line-tool

I installed command line tools using
xcode-select --install.
If I do 
cd  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin,   I can see gcc listed there.

I am trying to install an external application on command line which give these errors

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_set:205:5: warning: 
      Use of the header <ext/hash_set> is deprecated. Migrate to <unordered_set>
      [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_set> is deprecated.  Migrate to ...
    ^
In file included from src/stl_logging_unittest.cc:34:
In file included from ./src/glog/stl_logging.h:76:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ext/hash_map:212:5: warning: 
      Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated. Migrate to <unordered_map>
      [-W#warnings]
#   warning Use of the header <ext/hash_map> is deprecated.  Migrate to ...
    ^
In file included from src/stl_logging_unittest.cc:34:
./src/glog/stl_logging.h:77:11: fatal error: 'ext/slist' file not found
# include <ext/slist>
          ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [stl_logging_unittest-stl_logging_unittest.o] Error 1
Done.
```